# Can I create a 3D presentation to use with 3D glasses?

Tags: presentations, 3d

I have a presentation to give in 2 months, and I want to WOW my viewers. (limited group of 6)

We have a 3D enabled 55" TV that I will use, and I wanted to know if there is any way I can create a real 3D presentation (depth included ofc)

I am not talking about a 3D effect of the text.

Is it possible?

- I will give each of my viewers compatible 3D glasses to use.

Comment: This seems to be the closest I can find http://www.taodyne.com/shop/en/ That said, effects are really just gimmick, I'd rather listen to an engaging presenter using WW-era blackboard than a buzzword spouting presenter using Ultra-HD monitor on top a Ferrari

Comment: @MartheenCahyaPaulo Post that as an answer, I'd upvote that.

Answer (score 4):

[Tao Presentations](http://www.taodyne.com/shop/en/) seems to be the answer, they support 3D both with glasses and without glasses. The free version put a color watermark on the top left (think about your average TV network logo). But please, please, read [Death by Powerpoint](http://www.slideshare.net/thecroaker/death-by-powerpoint) before you do anything. Engaging presenter with plain blackboard is better than boring presenter using whatever latest tech.

EDIT : I just tried putting stuff into it. Personally I like SmartArt features in Office 2007 and above better to visualize concepts and points than the simplistic feature in Tao. Also, will these viewers of yours be comfortable in viewing the 3D display? My experiences with 3D display watching 3D music videos /playing 3D games are usually few minutes of wow followed by watery eyes for hours.

Answer (score 0):

Tao Presentations delivers really interesting 3D capabilities (movies, objects, 3D text), but it it has a steep learning curve (don't try it if you can't code). Their [developer web site](http://www.taodyne.com/shop/dev/en/) is a better starting point than the main web site. Read the [blog article about their document language](http://www.taodyne.com/shop/dev/en/blog/271-animation-and-3d-the-web-is-doing-it-wrong) to understand how it's supposed to work. The article is long, but it's funny and a good read. This software definitely takes some adjustment. You'll love it or you'll hate it.

Answer (score -1):

Disclaimer - I work at this company.

You can use Presente3D, it is an add-on for Microsoft PowerPoint 2007/2010/2013.

It works with any 3DTV, 3D-enabled projector and Non-3D TV's through the use of Anaglyph (Red/Blue) glasses.

http://www.presente3D.com

Comment: Welcome to superuser. From what I can tell, you're affliated with this product somehow, and as per the [faq], really need to make it clearer. In addition, its considered good form to answer other questions, as opposed to entirely using SU as a way to promote your products - it may be seen as spam, and will probably result in downvotes and spam flags. On the short term, fixing your answer will help. On the longer term, make it clear you're here as part of the community, and not just seeing it as a way to sell your product by participating. Thank you